# Inverse function of function defined in parts

Tags: calculus

This is part of a larger solved problem but I can't seem to get this part:

Define the function $ f:[0:1] \cup (2,3] \rightarrow [0,2] $ by setting
$ f(x)= x $ when $0 \le x \le 1$ and $ f(x)=x-1 $ when $ 2 \lt x \le 3 $.

The inverse function of $f$ is $ f^{-1}(x)= x $ when $0 \le x \le 1 $ and $ f^{-1}(x)= x+1 $ when $ 1 \lt x \le 2 $.

How did we get the inverse funtion here since the original function is defined in parts and why did we change the interval $ 2 \lt x \le 3 $ to $ 1 \lt x \le 2 $?

Answer (score 1):

Functions defined by parts can have inverse defined by parts.

Why did it change the interval? Because you are changing the world of input of f is the world of output of the inverse of f and the output of f is the input of the inverse of f.

If you apply $f(x) = x$ to $X = [0,1]$, then $Y = [0,1]$. If you apply $f(x) = x - 1$ to $X=[2,3]$, then $f(2) = 1$ and $f(3) = 2$, therefore $Y= [1,2]$ not $[2,3]$.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is a bijection from $A = [0,1]\cup (2, 3]$ to $B = [0,2]$, hence its inverse function has $B$ as domain and $A$ as image.

Answer (score 0):

The function has two parts. The first part which is $ f(x)=x$ on the interval $[0,1]$ is one-to-one and maps $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$ with its inverse being $f^{-1}(x)=x$, because the inverse of the identity function is the identity function.

The second part is $f(x)=x-1$ on the interval $(2,3]$ which maps $(2,3]$ onto $(1,2]$ and is  one-to -one with the inverse function of $f^{-1}(x)=x+1$.

Thus the inverse function for your $f(x)$ is defined on $[0,2]$ with the given two formulas.